# Measure of the set $Z \times N$, where $Z$ has zero measure and $N$ is non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a zero measure set $Z \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a non-measurable set $N \subset \mathbb{R}$. I want to conclude that $\lambda(Z \times N)=0$. I know that
$$
Z \times N \subset Z \times \mathbb{R} 
$$
and $\lambda(Z \times \mathbb{R}) = \lambda(Z) \lambda(\mathbb{R}) = 0 \cdot \infty = 0$
so $\lambda(Z \times N) \leq \lambda(Z \times \mathbb{R}) =0$, which begs the question of measurability of $Z \times N$. Are we to conclude that it is measurable because the Lebesgue measure is complete.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this set is mesurable and it has measure 0. One of the properties of Lebesgue measure is as follows:

If $A \subseteq B$, $B$ is measurable and $\lambda(B)=0$, then $A$ is measurable and $\lambda(A)=0$.

This is exactly what you need here.